I want to implement Role based access control in the react App
I want to implement role based access control in the react App. Is there any way azure role can we use for this and how can i used. Azure default role or Role creation anything how to use in react App.
I will be using azure for deployment of the application.
Let me know if any documentation and video you have
RBAC implementation where i don't have to create role manually and store in table. with azure help i will get role and i can use those role

Are you using azure authenticaton for your react app

yes we are using azure only

I guess that you want to implement the roles from the Azure ad, and assign those roles to the users in AD, and you want to create a roles-based access control to your react application based on the roles that you defined on the Azure ad

https://medium.com/@bablulawrence/securing-azure-functions-using-easy-auth-and-app-roles-bdef154356bd

How To Implement Role-Based Access Control(RBAC) Into Web Application Using Azure
1. Create An App Registration
In the Azure portal, App registration -> Register an app.

Add Name, Select Accounts in this organizational directory, and register the app.
2. Create App Roles
In the navigation blade, select App Roles And create app roles. I will go with the Admin and User app roles.

Admin Role Creation.

User Role Creation

You can view the created app roles.

3. Assign Roles To Users
Navigate to the Enterprise Application section in the Azure AD. Under all applications, select the app that you created previously. Select Users and Groups from the side navigation blade.

Add users, select the user and the role for that user.


Click Assign.
You will see the users that assign the roles.

4. Add Authentication In-App Registration
In-App Registration, Navigate to the Authentication tab.

Add Platform, Single-Page Application and add. http://localhost:3000 As the redirect URL. (You have to add your localhost react app URL)


5. Configure the React App
clone the repository and replace the values in the config/msalConfig.ts with the values from the app registration overview page client Id and the tenat Id .
.env
VITE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
VITE_TENANT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

6. Testing
In the dashboard page, click login; after that, you will see the roles assigned to the user. Store it in local storage or context and do the private route in the react-router-dom.

GitHub Repository
Thank You.
Sources.
microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/samples/msal-react-samples/typescript-sample at dev ·…
*Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for JS. Contribute to AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js…*github.com
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-react

Thanks for the info
Can we do like this
Create a admin role and assign the admin role other roles like global administration
and assign the admin to particular User
Thank You

You want to do the role management from the react application without using the azure portal

No i want to use azure only .. but i want to assign the default roles like global administration to the admin (custom role) which i created not to the user directly..
and the assign the admin to the role to user
is that possible

I didn't get that. Can you explain it again? is global administration is a custom role

What azure is giving
Global Administration (Some Default Role)--> Assign to login user(sanjay)--->sanjay assign to custom role (Admin)
What i want
Global Administration(Some Default Role)--->  Assing to custom role(Admin or User)--> these role then we can assign to login user (sanjay)
I hope i m clear this time..
Can we do this

yes that can be done
